# As this done in html5

Tags: html, video, banner-ads

one of my client as me which type of banners are these.
can you guys help me out in reaching to the answer of it.
https://www.instagram.com/p/BJZlC-djHAi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(video?) for me it is looking like normal video in adobe after effects. JS control play and pause. --> hese is only video: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/14082755_1756897074552500_1371943552_n.mp4